# .Net's unavailable "Extension Property" like functionality

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, treeview

Let us say I have a hierarchy represented by a "Person" class. The `ParentPerson` property in `Person` class (of type `Person`) enables the hierarchical representation and it can be any level deep. It does not have to be exactly this way but just imagine this need irrespective of the implementation.

The hierarchy needs to be displayed in a treeview control. Unassociated with the hierarchy but associated with the UI, I would like to have properties such as `IsExpanded` (or collapsed) to store which nodes have to be expanded or collapsed in the display. These attributes clearly do not belong to the `Person` class.

Is the best way to do this by inheriting the `Person` class and adding the necessary UI related properties? I understand that "extension properties" (like extension methods) are not available in .Net.

I do not want to wrap using extension methods as suggested here because I would like the added properties to be bindable in a WPF treeview.

What is the best/right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an architectural design pattern such as (in the case of WPF) Model–View–ViewModel (MVVM). There is an excellent article specifically for this scenario: [Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode). The recommendation is to create a `PersonViewModel` that wraps your `Person` objects (including instances of derived classes), exposing just the properties relevant for the UI, along with new `IsSelected` and `IsExpanded` properties that can be bound to by the `TreeViewItem` elements.